# XMLreq.Open "GET", url, False XMLreq.send 500 eror

Tags: excel, vba

[image: 1]

Hello friends. I would like to include some information from the site into Excel, but it gives this error. When you type a link to another site, the search disappears. Do you know how I can eliminate this error without any trouble?

Do you know how I can eliminate this error without any trouble?

Comment: What's the url?

Comment: 500 is "server error", so it's not going to be possible for us to figure out the cause of that error.  Maybe check the content of `xmlReq.responseText` for clues.

Comment: https://umico.az/product/305993-metbex-kombayni-kenwood-kmix-kmx-750-rd this url or the urls of different products on this site